# Is there a way to "fill out" a $n\times n$ matrix so that the determinant is the same as an$ m\times m$ matrix with $m < n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Say I have a $3\times3$ matrix: \begin{bmatrix}x&y&1\\0&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix} The determinant is then $y-1$, is there a way to fill out a strictly larger matrix that still contains the original so that the determinant remains $y-1$?

This is an example of what I am describing but I am not sure that this reflection into the lower left "quadrant" thing I did is true for all matrices.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant%5B%7Bx%5E2,xy,y%5E2,x,y,1%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,1,1%7D,%7B0,0,0,1,1,1%7D,%7B0,0,1,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,1,1,0,0,0%7D,%7B1,1,1,0,0,0%7D%5D+%3D+determinant%5B%7Bx,y,1%7D,%7B0,1,1%7D,%7B1,1,1%7D%5D

Comment: Just add ones down the diagonal, and zeros everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

For example

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}x&y&1\\0&1&1\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}=\det\begin{pmatrix}x&y&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\1&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=\det\begin{pmatrix}x&y&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0&0\\1&1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=etc.$$

Comment: What if the polynomial grows as the matrix grows like in my example?

Comment: @JasonB What polynomial? The characteristic? Of course it will always be a polynomial of bigger degree, if that's what you mean. Yet you only asked for  matrices with the same determinant

Comment: The polynomial that you would get if you were to read the row with the variables in it as a polynomial so x + y + 1, x^2 +xy +y^2 + x + y +1, etc. I'm not familiar with what a characteristic of a matrix is yet, sorry.

Comment: @JasonB The determinant of the first, $\;3\times3\;$ matrix you wrote is $$x+y-x-1=y-1$$ , and **all** the other matrices' determinant is exactly the same. I don't know if this is what you're asking in your comments above, but this is what *you* asked in your original post. I honestly don't understand what does "poly. grows as the matrix grows like in my example" mean: the DETERMINANTS in the above matrices are identical.